# Vim Basic - how to open multiple files

Tags: vim

If I opened a console and typed

```
vim example.*
```

while having 3 files `example.html`, `example.css` and `example.js`

Vim will open but how can I toggle between those files?

What are the different variations of opening multiple files in Vim? I am familiar with tabs but I am curious to know about your favorite way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `:n` to skip to the next file. Restart from the beginning with `:rew`

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer splits or tab pages, you can add the `-o` / `-O` / `-p` argument (see `:help starting`). But for many arguments, the default *argument list* is still the most practical solution, especially since you can apply batch changes via `:argdo`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `split file.c` from command line in vi editor

Answer (score 1):

Use `vim -p file1 file2` that will open the files in tabs. Use `:tabnext` and `:tabprev` to navigate or even better: `map gl :tabnext<cr>` and `map gh :tabprev<cr>` then you can change tabs even faster.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of plugin to ease the buffer management in Vim.

I am using [buxeplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42), but [minibufexplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159) is also popular.

If you want a generic answer, without using a specific plugin, there a some [articles](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easier_buffer_switching) around.